# reading a text file c# and delimited by size

Tags: c#, file, text, size, csv

Below is my data example of text file

00001000100100000011000111

I know that the first two numbers of my message is my string init = "00"  <- always these numbers.

after I have 4 numbers that means my "message quantity" like if I will send "two" message -> 0010  binary number.

after I have my first message "24", the code is "0010 0100"  binary number.

than I have my second message "31", the code is "0011 0001" but before put these numbers I must separated using "00".

finally, I have my string end ="11" <- always these numbers

the message need to be separated like these:
00 0010 0010 0100 00 0011 0001 11

I have to read this file and show what is the message. "24" and "31".

Can someone help me? remembering that for this example I just have "two" message but I coud have "one" or "three" or .....

rules: If i have more than "one" message, i need to separated using "00"

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load them in as strings, use the substring string method, and grab the substrings by size. However, your actual message must be the same lenth, or you need a length indicator also, to specify when a message ends. Because 00, might be part of the actual message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (I kept code simpliest I could, so I think it's clean enough itself):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> messages = new List<int>();

    int blockSize = 4;

    string binary = "00001000100100000011000111";

    int howManyMessages = BinToInt(binary.Substring(2, blockSize));
    // if there is no messages, return
    if (howManyMessages == 0) return;
    // read first message
    int firstMessage = BinToInt(binary.Substring(2 + blockSize, 2 * blockSize));
    messages.Add(firstMessage);
    // if there is just one message, we just read it, so end
    if (howManyMessages == 1) return;
    // read the rest of messages
    for (int i = 2; i <= howManyMessages; i++)
        messages.Add(BinToInt(binary.Substring(2 + blockSize + 2 * (1 + blockSize), 2 * blockSize)));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
// convert binary number in string to integer
private static int BinToInt(string bin)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bin.Length; i++)
        result += int.Parse(bin[bin.Length - 1 - i].ToString()) * (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
    return result;
}
```